# Exchange Mail Flow

Tags: exchange-migration

I have a question. We have one Exchange 2003 server and two Exchange 2007 servers. Most all of our mailboxes are on 2007 but we do still have one shared mailbox, unity mailbox and a journling mailbox on 2003. Public Folders have been set to replicate to 2007. I have set up a send connector on 2007 with a cost of 1. Receive connectors have Anonymous Users checked on 2007. On 2003 there are two connectors: the Internet Email connector and the connector that connects 2003 to 2007. We have a SPAM filtering device that email goes through before it is handed off to Exchange. The SPAM filtering device is set to send email to one of our Exchange 2007 servers. Here is my question/problem: Even though the SPAM filtering device is set to forward email to Exchange 2007, somehow all of our email is still going through the Exchange 2003 server before it finally hits the users mailboxes on the Exchange 2007 server. How can I change it so that all email goes directly to Exchange 2007 and never routes through Excahnge 2003 both ways, inbound and outbound?

Would also like to add:

In the EMC under Org- Hub- Send Connector there are two connectors. One is the "Internet Connector" from the 2003 box and the other is the new one I created. THe address space on the 2003 one is set to a cost of 2, no smart hosts and the 2003 box is listed as the Source Server. THe other Send Connector has an address space of 1, no smart host and has the 2 excahnge 2007 servers listed as the source servers.

In EMC under Server- Hub- my two exchange 2007 servers are listed. Each one has 2 receive connectors. Both Recieve Connectors are setup the same way. THe Default Receive Connector has Anonymous Users checked. The other Recieve Connector is labled "Client" and I am not sure what it does or why its there. Anonymous Users are not checked.

No smart hosts configured on 2003.

*Additional details*

---

Currently we have 3 excahnge servers. One exchange 2003 server and two excahnge 2007 servers. THe exchange 2003 server is the acting "bridgehead" serverand all email is routing through this server, inbound and outbound. We are wanting to decommission this server and use our two exchange 2007 servers as our mailbox servers. All of of user mailboxes are already on one of the exchange 2007 boxes and we want to put whats left on the exchange 2003 box on our other excahnge 2007 box. Both excahnge 2007 servers are currently CAS, HT and MB servers. We have a SPAM filtering device that sits between our excahnge servers and the firewall and have it configured to send messages to one of the excahgne 2007 servers but when we look at the message headers we can see that messgaes are still being routed to the excahnge 2003 box. We want to bypass the exchange 2003 in the routing process as it is dying and is starting to have major issues so everytime it goes down our email is down. Is there possible some sort of AD routing link/site link stuff going on?

Comment: I moved your answer to an edit within the original question - this helps new readers to understand the situation more easily, and get your question answered quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this issue is now solved! It was a "hidden" setting in our SPAM filtering device. We just had to change it from the Exchange 2003 IP to the Exchange 2007 IP address.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2006/11/17/431555.aspx) is pretty thorough about everything you should take a look at to make sure your receive connector is properly set up.  I had a similar problem, and it was just a matter of finding all of those settings in various nooks & crannies.

I'm not sure what exactly happens if you don't use /PrepareLegacyExchange before installation, but I thought I'd throw that out there.

---

In case it helps, you should only need one receive connector - on the Hub Transport server for the site.  If you have the HT role installed on both boxes... that may not be ideal.  Try trimming it down to a single Receive connector.  So long as you have ONE HT server in an AD site, it'll route mail to the correct Mailbox server.

Feel free to give more detail about your intent for each exchange server as well as which Exchange roles are installed on which servers if things still aren't clear.  I'll shed light where I can.

Comment: Would I just need to delete the Internet send connector on Exchange 2003 or would this cause other problems?

Comment: I don't have my 2003 box available currently, but I'm hoping you can just disable the connector, rather than disable it?  In my case, the only reason mail was flowing through my 2003 server was because I hadn't yet properly set up the 2007 box.  Once I got things fixed, I was able to power down the old server entirely.  I'll wait another couple of weeks and then start the process of removing its remnants from AD.

Comment: This is unrelated but I really enjoyed the Exchange 2007 SP2 experience when decommissioning it for Exchange 2010. The updated uninstaller simply walked you through all steps needed to uninstall the 2007 server, preventing you from doing it if any little routing detail was wrong or anything was missing on the new servers... ^^

Answer (score 0):

Now that you mention it, Exchange 2007 (unlike 2003) uses the site information in Active Directory Sites and Services for routing.  I wouldn't think it would have an effect in a single-site setup, but it's worth poking around to make sure ADSS is properly set up.

Nothing else jumps out at me right away, unfortunately. There are a ton of articles on the [You had me at EHLO site](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2006/11/17/431555.aspx) that pretty much walked me through my 2003-to-2007 woes, though it took some time.

Comment: Ok, thank you. We are going to start by disabling the "Internet Email" connector this weekend and see what that does. Hopefully this will cause all messages to be routed directly to our exchange 2007 servers.

Comment: I'm going to add that we were able to get mail routing through the 2007 box without removing any settings enabling the 2003 box to work.  That is, we only had to change mail flow at the firewall level.  I suspect there's still some configuration change that still needs to be made in ADSS or 2007.  Wish I could be more helpful.